How to stop Ionic VS Code extension automatically adding import statement
Each time I save a .html file in my angular app, the Ionic extension adds this line to the corresponding .ts file: import { addIcons } from "ionicons";
While, I do use Ionic in other app I develop, the current app I am working on is not using Ionic. Here is the package.json
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "build:development",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "start": "ng serve --configuration=development",
    "start:production": "ng serve --configuration=production",
    "build:development": "ng build --configuration=development --base-href=./ --aot --optimization",
    "build:production": "ng build --configuration=production --output-path=Client/ --base-href=./ --aot --optimization",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^18.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^18.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^18.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.5.2"
  }
}

It looks like I have the Ionic v1.93.1 installed.
I am using angular 18 and material, somehow I guess Ionic thinks mat-icon is an ionic component and thus adds the import statement.
I've looked at the ionic settings in vs code and nothing is available to stop this feature.
Please let me know if there is a way to stop this (without uninstalling or disabling the Ionic extension).

I've updated the question to ask for ways of resolving this without uninstalling OR disabling the extension. I have found that disabling the extenson is a relatively easy solution, but a better one would be for the feature to be able to be disabled.

I've tried to use the JavaScript (and TypeScript) Auto Import File Exlude Patterns setting, and could not get it to work for node_modules, and other patterns, but this could be the path forward.

as of now, there is no way other than disabling the extension. It's a shame Ionic team couldn't come up with a better way to import icons. importing one by one is a hassle.

I had this problem and it was caused by de 'official ionic extension'. I just disabled the plugin and the problem was solved (I was not in a ionic project).

Isn't this not controlled by visual studio code?
You can turn this off by searching for "auto" under File > Preference > Setting, and then turn off the checkbox by "Auto Imports".

Which specific setting? I've turned everything off that I can see and it still auto imports.e.g. Include Package JSON Auto Imports= off; Javascript Suggest: Auto Imports: unchecked etc.

I meant the Javascript Suggest: Auto Imports: unchecked

I unchecked that and Javascript > Suggest Include Completions for Import Statements. Also unchecked the Typescript for the same (of both mentioned settings). Problem still exists.

Then maybe try to post your question in the Ionic-Forum

This appears to be a bug after a VS-code auto update as posted on the Ionic forums. The solution posted was to disable and re-enable the ionic extension.
